# Trying to access two queries of BigQuery through Firebase Cloud Functions HTTP Triggers(date function)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

```
 exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
 const bigQuery = bigquery({ projectId: 'project' });
        var someVar = [];
        var someVar1 =[];
        bigQuery.query({

      query:'Select email from(inner_query)',
      useLegacySql: false
    }).then(function (rows) {
      setValue(rows);

  });
  function setValue(value) {
    someVar = value;
    //console.log(someVar); // data is printing here

    var someVar = value[0].map(function(o) { return o.email; });

    //console.log(someVar); 

    var i,datalength;
    datalength = someVar.length;
    for(i=0;i<=datalength;i++){
     //console.log(someVar[i])

      bigQuery.query({
      query:'Insert(first query output in a table)',
          useLegacySql: false
        }).then(function (rows) {
          setValue(rows);

      });
           }
             }
                });
```

Trying to run two queries in a single http date function but my second query is not working means unable to insert output of first query in a table through second query? And when i m running both the queries in bigquery query console both are working fine but through cloud functions insert query is not working?
Any Clue??

Comment: Why you doing it this way? I think it is much simpler if you just do streaming of result to target table? Could you also share error message you got in log when insert failed?

Comment: Is your first query working? Are you able to retrieve the result?

Comment: Have you included all dependencies [(1)](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/bigquery-import/functions/package.json) in your package.json? You also need to add Firebase Admin SDK in order to access Google Cloud Platform resources [(2)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).